# Spring Kafka and auto ack timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I use Kafka message broker and Spring Kafka.

I use default auto-acknowledgment model. Sometimes my `@KafkaListener` needs ~5 minutes in order to complete the work.

I noticed that when it occurs the Kafka produces duplicate messages.
Is there any timeout property that can be configured in order to prevent Kafka to repeat the same message and let Producer wait (at least for example 10 minutes) while Consumer will complete the work?

Comment: Producers and Consumers are decoupled - there is no built-in way to stop the producer from sending more messages because the consumer is slow.
You need to show more information - which version of spring-kafka, which version of kafka etc; logs would be helpful too. I generally avoid `auto.commit`; it's generally better to let the spring container manage the offsets.

Comment: Thanks. I use Kafka 1.0.0 and Spring Kafka 2.0.0.RELEASE. I may be wrong but looks like Producer(or Kafka itself) repeats the same message when Consumer is working for a long time. Is there any timeout properties for this case in order to let Consumer work for at least 10 minutes and Kafka will not repeat the same message until this time?

Comment: Also, I do not use auto.commit explicitly. I use default Spring configuration

Answer (score 5):

Producers and Consumers are decoupled - there is no way to stop the producer from sending more messages because the consumer is slow.

> I do not use auto.commit explicitly. I use default Spring configuration

`auto.commit` is `true` by default (in the Kafka client) so the default behavior under spring is for the client to do its own commits rather than the container. Set it to `false` and set the container properties `AckMode` to `RECORD` so the commit is performed after the listener exits.

There is a [kafka consumer property](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) `max.poll.interval.ms` which defaults to 5 minutes (300000).

> The maximum delay between invocations of poll() when using consumer group management. This places an upper bound on the amount of time that the consumer can be idle before fetching more records. If poll() is not called before expiration of this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member.

The rebalance will cause a redelivery. You can increase that property to avoid the rebalance.

As I said, logs generally help; you should see the rebalance occurring in the log.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I need some time to test it. Right after that, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: >`I use Kafka 1.0.0 and Spring Kafka 2.0.0.RELEASE.` - BTW, 2.1.0.RELEASE uses 1.0.0 natively and was explicitly released to do so; it will bring in 1.0.0 transitively. Our rules don't allow us to change a client version and 2.0.0.RELEASE (now at 2.0.2) had already been released to use the 0.11.0.x client before 1.0.0 was available.

Comment: @alexanoid have you been testing this for 5 years!?